# Laravel Voyager Rest Api

Tags: php, laravel, voyager

I use Laravel Voyager last version Laravel 9, Voyager 1.6 and next packages:

https://github.com/rxcod9/joy-voyager-api

https://github.com/rxcod9/joy-voyager-api-auth

They generated a swagger for me with all models what i created in Voyager admin.
When trying to get any data from the documentation, it returns the error No query results for model [Laravel\Passport\Client]. Has anyone used these modules? How to configure them correctly, do i need to register all routes manually?